# two-way MANCOVA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, manova

I am currently trying to run a two way MANCOVA as I have to independent variables with 2 levels each 1) sleep chronotype (late and early) and weekly sleep loss (high and low). I have four dependent variables (score and speed for planning) and (score and number of positive choices for gambling).  I also have one covariate which is depression. I was wondering if it is okay to have 2 dependent variables for one measure such as score and speed.  Also I was wondering if a two way mancova is the same as 1 way mancova with an additional independent variable and all the assumptions are similiar too. I cannot find any information on two way Mancova on any books or websites.

Answer (score 1):

These are two of my go to sites (statisticshowto and laerd). The statistics how to link below discusses how the assumptions of a mancova are the same as that of a manova except with a couple other ones for the covariates (which they discuss in that site). Thus, if you take the assumptions from the two way manova (on the laerd link below) and add on the assumptions of the covariate (from the statisticshowto link), you should be covered.

https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/mancova/

https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-manova-using-spss-statistics.php

Additionally, you asked about having 2 DVs for one measure (i.e., score and speed for planning). I would usually say look to the literature for how those measures were used in the past. For instance, have score and speed been used as separate measures to get at planning before. It sounds like this may not be a validated scale from the literature, though. If that's the case and it's just a value for score and speed, I would suggest checking to make sure they're not too correlated with each other ( > .95) to ensure there isn't redundancy in your measures thus indicating you are just measuring the same thing with two separate things. If the correlation is not too high, you should be fine to use both of them as two separate DVs.

Comment: Thank you very much Brittany for your helpful answer. I appreciate it very much

Comment: No worries. If you found my response to answer your question you can upvote it and check it as answered